# Ubuntu 14.04 service log file deleted, logs not being written to new files

Tags: logging, service

I deleted `/etc/sv/<service>/log/current` while this service was running and wanted to get a clean set of logs. However, when I did `sudo service <service> restart`, I saw that the `current` file was not re-created and I can't find where the new logs are going to. I then tried to make the file myself, and even gave the loosest write permission and saw that the file still is not being written to. Here's the `ls -la` of this directory(after I created the `current` file):

```
-rwxr--r-- 1 root root   92989 Sep 26 18:08 @400000005d8cfea82484f9e4.s
-rwxr--r-- 1 root root  353827 Sep 26 19:08 @400000005d8d0cb826d2f50c.s
-rwxr--r-- 1 root root  272084 Sep 26 19:45 @400000005d8d1ac8286c4a1c.s
-rwxr--r-- 1 root root  332117 Sep 26 21:00 @400000005d8d28d82f65f304.s
-rwxr--r-- 1 root root 1678531 Sep 26 22:08 @400000005d8d36e8308de4bc.s
-rwxr--r-- 1 root root 2143833 Sep 26 23:08 @400000005d8d44f831d170dc.s
-rwxr--r-- 1 root root 1549498 Sep 27 00:08 @400000005d8d5308332767d4.s
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      33 Jan 31  2019 config
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root       0 Sep 27 00:43 current
-rw------- 1 root root       0 Jan 31  2019 lock
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    4096 Jan 31  2019 main
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      40 Jan 31  2019 run
drwx------ 2 root root    4096 Feb 21  2019 supervise
```

What can I do to bring back the `current` log and restart the log rotation on this service?

`ps auxf` gives me this particular line that seems interesting:

```
root      1269  0.0  0.0    176    44 ?        Ss   Feb21   0:17  \_ runsv <service>
root      1272  0.0  0.0    200    56 ?        S    Feb21  15:41  |   \_ svlogd -b 2048 -l 2000 .
root     29245  0.0  3.9 503232 299256 ?       Sl   00:55   0:22  |   \_ /usr/bin/python3 <some service>
```

I can see the log subservice here, but I'm not sure what command I can use to restart that subservice itself.

Answer (score 0):

The log file (usually) gets written by the `log` sub-service, not the main service.  You need to restart the `log` sub-service in order for it to close the file it's writing to and re-open it.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer! how would I restart a particular subservice? I have updated in my question the exact subservice you're talking about

Comment: I have no idea, I don't use `runit`; `sv restart /etc/sv/<service>/log` would probably do it.  Worst case, just whack the `svlogd` process and the supervisor should automagically restart it.